# Groups with a perfect commutator subgroup

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, abelian-groups

**Problem**: Find a pair of nonisomorphic nonabelian groups so that their abelianizations are isomorphic and their commutator subgroups are perfect.

I am not sure if this is a correct solution or not, it would be nice if anyone could spot a mistake if exists.

**Solution**: **(a)** For $n \geq 5$, the symmetric group $S_n$ has abelianization isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and its commutator subgroup is the alternating group $A_n$, which is perfect. Let's analyze the abelianization and commutator subgroup for $S_n$ in general.

1. Abelianization of $S_n$:
   The abelianization of a group $G$ is given by $G/[G, G]$, where $[G, G]$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$. For the symmetric group $S_n$, the commutator subgroup is the alternating group $A_n$. Therefore, the abelianization of $S_n$ is $S_n/A_n$.

For $n \geq 3$, the index of $A_n$ in $S_n$ is $2$. This means that the quotient group $S_n/A_n$ has two elements, and thus, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. For $n=2$, $S_2$ is already abelian and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. For $n=1$, $S_1$ is the trivial group with only one element, and thus, its abelianization is also the trivial group.

In conclusion, the abelianization of $S_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for $n \geq 2$ and is the trivial group for $n=1$.

2. Commutator subgroup of $S_n$:
   For the symmetric group $S_n$, the commutator subgroup is the alternating group $A_n$. The alternating group $A_n$ consists of all even permutations of $n$ elements, which are those permutations that can be expressed as a product of an even number of transpositions.

For $n \geq 5$, the alternating group $A_n$ is perfect, meaning it is equal to its commutator subgroup. This is because $A_n$ is simple for $n \geq 5$, which means it has no normal subgroups other than the trivial group and itself. Since the commutator subgroup is always a normal subgroup, it must be that $[A_n, A_n] = A_n$ for $n \geq 5$. For $n < 5$, $A_n$ is not perfect.

In conclusion, the commutator subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$, and for $n \geq 5$, $A_n$ is perfect.

**(b)** For the other part, we follow the hints provided in the comments and construct a group $G$ with $A_n$ as a subgroup of index 2.

Consider the direct product of $A_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, denoted as $G = A_n \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. By construction, $A_n$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index 2. The group $G$ is nonabelian since $A_n$ is nonabelian for $n \geq 5$. Moreover, $G$ is not isomorphic to $S_n$, as the elements in $G$ have the form $(a, b)$, where $a \in A_n$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, whereas the elements in $S_n$ are just permutations.

Now let's check the properties of the abelianization and the commutator subgroup of $G$.

1. Abelianization of $G$:

Since $A_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ are both normal subgroups of $G$, we can apply the following result about abelianizations of direct products: If $G = A \times B$, then $G' = A' \times B'$, where $G'$ is the abelianization of $G$, and $A'$ and $B'$ are the abelianizations of $A$ and $B$, respectively.

For $n \geq 5$, the abelianization of $A_n$ is trivial, as $A_n$ is perfect. The abelianization of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is itself since it is already abelian. Therefore, the abelianization of $G$ is the trivial group $\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is the same as the abelianization of $S_n$ for $n \geq 5$.

2. Commutator subgroup of $G$:

The commutator subgroup of a direct product is the direct product of the commutator subgroups: $[G, G] = [A_n, A_n] \times [\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}]$. Since $A_n$ is perfect for $n \geq 5$, we have $[A_n, A_n] = A_n$. The commutator subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial, as it is abelian. Thus, the commutator subgroup of $G$ is $A_n \times \{0\} \cong A_n$, which is perfect for $n \geq 5$.

In conclusion, for $n \geq 5$, the groups $S_n$ and $G = A_n \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ are nonisomorphic nonabelian groups with abelianizations isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and their commutator subgroups are perfect.

Comment: But the question asks you to find two non-isomorphic nonabelian groups with these properties. What are your two groups? One of them could be $S_n$ for $n \ge 5$. What is the other group?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you for your comment. Yeah, considering if $S_n$ has indeed satisfied those properties correctly, I was actually wondering what can be the second such group. Speaking of that, is my solution also correct?

Comment: Yes $S_n$ for $n \ge 5$ has the required properties. Now you need to think of another group $G$ with $G/[G,G]$ of order $2$ and $[G,G] \cong A_n$. Such a $G$ does exist!

Comment: I am sorry @DerekHolt but I really can't think of another such $G$. Can you please provide solution of this as it can make things more clear

Comment: I edited the solution. Can you check if the second group is correct or not @ThePhoenix

Comment: Yes that is now correct!

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you for your comment, appreciate it a lot!